# ini_set for xdebug.remote_enable not work

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to disable xdebug on "Prod" environment(in php.ini this option is "1") via command:

```
ini_set('xdebug.remote_enable', '0');
```

But this is not work, phpinfo show this option value is enabled. What am I doing wrong?
According to the documentation it should work http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have permission to change it from php script. The permission is set to `PHP_INI_PERDIR` which means **"Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)"**. Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: That is no way to disable/enable it depending on my application environment?

Comment: That particular ini variable can't be set from php scripts.

Comment: @maximkou Why not just use the .htaccess file option?

Comment: @leftclickben, My front_prod.php and front_dev.php located in one folder.

Comment: @MladenB., thanks. It seems that there are no more solutions.

Comment: @maximkou So, `s/front_(\S+)\.php/$1\/front.php/g`  ...and move the files appropriately :-)